# Override oneToMany Template in Symfony and Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have an entity Post which has many Comments and I have included as follows in my PostAdmin.php

```
->tab('Comments')
        ->with('')
          ->add('comments', 'sonata_type_collection', array('by_reference' => false,'disabled' => false, 'label' => ' ', 'required' => false,
              'type_options' => array(

                  'delete' => false,
                  'btn_add' => false
              )
          ), array(
              'edit' => 'inline',

          ))
        ->end()
      ->end();
```

I have already customised edit.html.twig to include javascripts that run some functions which are unrelated to this question.

I would like to override the comments block in edit.html.twig to include some ajax functionality for buttons that would then publish, delete or edit a single comment from all the listed comments under the article.

How would I go about this?